# Error #1054 : Unknown Column - function sql query

Tags: mysql

I'm getting error#1054 when I'm trying to restore my database at another computer.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` FUNCTION `GetLabResultTag`
(pLABRESULTTAG VARCHAR(1)) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    #DECLARE pTMP Varchar(20);
    return (case when pRADRESULTTAG='C' then 'CHARGE'
        when pRADRESULTTAG='D' then 'DRAFT'
        when pRADRESULTTAG='F' then 'FINAL'
        when pRADRESULTTAG='P' then 'PERFORMED'
        when pRADRESULTTAG='R' then 'REVOKED'
        when pRADRESULTTAG='M' then 'CREDIT MEMO'
        when pRADRESULTTAG='V' then 'RECEIVED'
        ELSE 'SCHEDULE' END); 
    #return pTMP;
    END
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Well it's true, the parameter you are passing is pLABRESULTTAG and the column you are testing is pRADRESULTTAG (which the function knows nothing about).

Comment: @P.Salmon so that means, I have to change it to `pLABRESULTTAG`?